# Missing devise mailer template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm getting a missing template error with devise - it's probably a simple error but I can't see it. I have -

```
../mailers/user_mailer.rb

class UserMailer < ::ActionMailer::Base
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers
  default :from => "my@emailaddress.com"
  def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
      @token = token
      devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
    end
...
```

...and a template generated by devise -

```
../views/users/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb
```

... but I'm getting a template missing error -

```
Missing template user_mailer/confirmation_instructions with "mailer". Searched in: * "user_mailer"
```

Why is the mailer template not being found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your **confirmation_instructions.html.erb** file should be in user_mailer folder in views.

path like this ../views/user_mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb

insted of this ../views/users/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb

Comment: Thanks!Same problem in 2020. I left the password_change.html.erb in the views/devise/mailer/. I made a copy and put it in the views/user_mailer/ and Voila I got my email!!